# Is there a colloquial phrase for a function with a specific domain?

Tags: functions

There seems to be a name for a function with a specific codomain. Namely, if the codomain is $D$, then we called it a $D$-valued function. For example, we have complex valued functions, real valued functions, etc.

Is there an analogous name for functions with a particular domain? It is very cumbersome to say 'a function whose domain is...' every single time.

Comment: $D$-domained? :) Really the question is not about mathematics, but about English.

Comment: @JohnB Yes, I understand that. However, it is something that I find a bit annoying, and have thus decided to consult the infinite wisdom of StackExchange. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Noted. By the way, you can check that "$D$-valued" is nonsense in many languages.

Answer (score 1):

Usually in a written text the shortest and most common way would be to write out both domain and codomain, as in "let $f:A\to B$". I can't really think of a context where you care about the domain but not the codomain.

However, when the domain is $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ you have the common phrasing "function of a real variable", or "function of a complex variable". It is also used with multiple variables, as in "function of $n$ complex variables", etc.

Comment: For more particular cases like mentioned here, have a look at the left of [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)), which includes the word 'sequence' to refer to functions from $\mathbb{Z}$, and 'ordered pair' to refer to functions from $\mathbb{B}$.